# jQuery Mobile CSS Conflict

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, grid, stack, navbar

bHello I have a question regarding jQuery mobile css.

I have a page and inside that page I have header,content and footer. Now inside the content I have a grid that has a bunch of textfields:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="calculator">



<div data-role="header" data-id="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"  data-icon="b" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"  data-icon="star" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="grid" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="search" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->​

<div data-role="content">

<!-- below is the grid -->

<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height:65px">Afvallen:<input type="text" name="m1cut" id="m1cut" value=""></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height:65px">Onderhoud:<input type="text" name="m1onderhoud" id="m1onderhoud" value=""></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height:65px">Aankomen:<input type="text" name="m1bulk" id="m1bulk" value=""></div></div>
</div>

</div><!-- /content -->

    <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Omhoog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Now, normally the grid seperates in 3 pieces of 33/33/33 (%), but I changed it too 100% each, so that it would stack on top of each other. I did that with the following css:

```
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-c,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-d {
    width:100%; 
}
```

Now, that worked as it should, but the problem I have now is that I want to have a navbar inside the header (as you can see in the code) but it also stacks up and has a width of 100%. When I remove the css for the grid it works perfectly (25/25/25/25) but then again the grid is 33/33/33 instead of 100 each, does anyone know why this css causes this conflict and how to solve it, its weird because I only edit the grid while it affects the navbar aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is if you want your divs to fill 100% why bother altering jQuery Mobile's css? You can just do a 3 divs and set width 100%.

I'd suggest you that you revert the css modification you did on jQuery Mobile's css and add custom css for your divs.

### Update

I tried your problem in jsfiddle and everything works fine after changing the css too http://jsfiddle.net/jEYNy/

```
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-c,
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-d {
    width:100%; 
}
```

instead of changing your jQuery Mobile's css, add your changed code as custom css and import it into your code and see how it behaves.

Comment: Okay i'll give that a go :)

Comment: I've seen it ;) , I don't know why mine screwed up but I have solved it by wrapping it in a custom div (class) with the same css and that worked the way I wanted it.